# vba detect/prevent delete row from quick access toolbar

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote code that will archive deleted rows in a worksheet into anoteher hidden sheet:

```
Application.CommandBars("Row").FindControl(ID:=293).OnAction = "ArchiveRow"
```

Unfortunately this only works when deleting rows through right click menu.

Is there a way to detect or prevent deleting rows through the quick access toolbar, or using a shortcut key?

Comment: Do you need the toolbars for anything or are you OK to hide them all completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround for this is to disable the shortcuts and quick access toolbar when the workbook activates, and then enable them again when it deactivates. Although, if you need the toolbar for other things, this may not be the best option:

In ThisWorkbook Object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"

    With Application
       .OnKey "^-", ""
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"

    With Application
       .OnKey "^-", "^-"
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you the following workaround:

- Make sure that you lock your worksheet, and when you lock it, you do not allow deletion of rows and columns.
- When you want to use your macro, set a trigger somewhere, which unprotects the sheet like this - `Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "mypassword"`.
- Then, at the end of the macro, you may protect the sheet again with this:
  `Sheets("Sheet1").Protect "mypassword"`

It will work, but I am not sure whether this is what you want.